# Plugin with id 'com.android.application' was already requested at line 1

Tags: firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I still don't understand why this happens. I didn't do nothing and suddenly I got this error says

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' was already requested at line 1

Here's the code

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.automaticgate"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.automaticgate"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.5")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0"))

    // Add the dependency for the Realtime Database library
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
}
```

Here's the error
[Error shows so many lines, so I'll just post the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waGqJ.png)

I've tried creating a new project under different names and package, but the problem remains the same. Please help, i might cry :')

Comment: it's because you have this line twice in your plugins section: id("com.android.application"), one of them at line 1, as your error message states

Answer (score 0):

You're applying two plugins twice:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}
```

Just remove the duplicates.